# ORIGINAL_LOGIN and SYSTEM_USER functions for auditing?

Tags: sql-server, triggers, auditing

I am implementing an inserted trigger and am considering using ORIGINAL_LOGIN function to capture the current executing user. I would like to know the pros and cons of using ORIGINAL_LOGIN for auditing. Under what scenario does SYSTEM_USER provide a better alternative to ORIGINAL_LOGIN?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`SYSTEM_USER` presents you with the credentials used to run the query. This is important to establish which permissions were active. `ORIGINAL_LOGIN` is giving you the user with which the connection was established. This is also important information.

### SYSTEM_USER

- Pro: you can see with which permissions a query was executed.
- Con:
  you don't know who originally created the connection

### ORIGINAL_LOGIN

- Pro: You see who created the connection.
- Con: You don't know with which permissions the query was executed.

To have correct audit results, both need to be logged.

Comment: Thanks Filip De Vos! As you have mentioned, I have decided to log both these details.

Comment: It's `ORIGINAL_LOGIN` and not `ORIGINAL_USER`, isn't it?